# Remove rpm package without its dependencies using Ansible

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible you can remove an rpm package with...

```
- name: Remove NetworkManager
  yum:
    name: NetworkManager
    state: absent
```

Is there any way I can specify not to remove the dependencies ?

Want something like... `sudo rpm -e --nodeps NetworkManager` ?

Comment: `autoremove: yes` should do that

Comment: @error404: the OP is looking for the other way around :). I think the goal is to break dependencies by removing a particular package and not the packages which are dependent on it (no clue why this would be useful in an automated scenario). In this particular case, the only solution is to use the `command` module with the exact rpm command. Note that a subsequent call to yum with ansible will likely fail as the rpmdb will contain dependency errors.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks I will be more careful next time before posting any comment. And yes as of now command module is the only solution that can work as per me as well

Comment: @error404: happens to the best ;)